# Parsing Nested JSON with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I know that there have been questions similar to this, but I've not yet been able to figure out how to do what I need to. I'm trying to take some JSON and move it into a Pandas DataFrame.

```
    {
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "Joe Jimmy",
      "timestamp": 1541547573
    },
    {
      "name": "Steven Peterson",
      "timestamp": 1541274647
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like the corresponding DataFrame to look like this:

```
     Name               Timestamp   
1 "Joe Jimmy"        "1541547573"
2 "Stephen Peterson" "1541274647"
```

I think the problem is that first nested "friends," but I'm not sure, as I'm new to JSON (and Pandas, really).

I've tried bringing it in via

```
 with open('data.json') as f:
   friends = json.load(f)
```

And then moving it to a dataframe via the Panadas DataFrame constructor, but I'm not getting out anything but this:

```
{'name': 'Brian B.S. Sheehan', 'timestamp': 15...}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. To improve your chances of getting an answer i suggest that you take a look at [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you get the help you seek much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with pandas `read_json`:

```
df = pd.read_json(r'C:\path\data.json')
df.friends.apply(pd.Series)

    name            timestamp
0   Joe Jimmy       1541547573
1   Steven Peterson 1541274647
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html 
Or just use read_json function and use groupby method

Try this:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from json import load

data_json = load(open("inp.json", "r"))
print(json_normalize(data_json,'friends'))
```

Comment: I figured it out. I just brought it in and used new_friends = pd.DataFrame(data['friends']) to get the second level into a DF. It's not pretty, but it worked.

Comment: I see. Thats great.